# Merge two arrays without PreDefined functions In javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to merge two arrays in Js. I have done this by learning a logic but getting an issue. I am getting undefined values at few indexes of new array.

````
  const arr3 = [];
  const length1= arr1.length;
  const length2 = arr2.length;
  let k = 0;
  const totalLength = length1 + length2;
  for(let i=0 ; i<=totalLength; i++){
      arr3.push(arr1[i]);
       if(i > length1){
        arr3.push(arr2[k]);
         k= k+1;
         }
  }
  return arr3;
}

merge([1,3,25,5], [5,4,9,7]); ```

i am getting an output
````

[1,3,25,5, undefined, undefined,5, undefined, 4 ,undefined, 9, undefined, 7]

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: [  1,  3, 25,  5,  5,  4,  9,  7 ]

Answer (score 1):

What you need:

- let the index be smaller than the length of both arrays,
- push only one item in the loop and
- check if the index is smaller than `length1`
- than pus from the first array
- otherwise take the value from the second array and adjust the index by subtracting the lenght of the index to get a zero based index.

```js
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
  const arr3 = [];
  const length1 = arr1.length;
  const length2 = arr2.length;
  let k = 0;
  const totalLength = length1 + length2;

  for (let i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) { // change to <
    if (i < length1) {
      arr3.push(arr1[i]);
    } else {
      arr3.push(arr2[i - length1]);
    }
  }
  return arr3;
}
console.log(merge([1, 3, 25, 5], [5, 4, 9, 7]));
```

Why not take two for statements, instead of looping over the length of both arrays?

```js
function merge(array1, array2) {
    var i, 
        result = [];
        
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) result.push(array1[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) result.push(array2[i]);
    
    return result;
}

console.log(merge([1, 3, 25, 5], [5, 4, 9, 7]));
```

Comment: Yes, thnku for your answer. Can you please tell me why my program was printing predefined there in array. I want to know the possible reason for my future studies.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use your code, so change it to:

```js
function merge(arr1,  arr2){
 
const arr3 = [];
  const length1= arr1.length;
  const length2 = arr2.length;
  let k = 0;
  const totalLength = length1 + length2;
  for(let i=0 ; i<totalLength; i++){
 
       if(i >= length1){
        arr3.push(arr2[k]);
         k= k+1;
         }else{
        arr3.push(arr1[i]);
         }
  }
  return arr3;
}

console.log(merge([1,3,25,5], [5,4,9,7]))
```

or use the other solution like this:

```js
const merge =(...arg) => [].concat(...arg);

console.log(merge([1,3,25,5],[5,4,9,7]))
```